# Storage::makeDirectory in public folder

Tags: php, laravel, storage

I'm trying to create folder in `public/storage` but when i call `Storage::makeDirectory("public/storage/newdirectory")` it creats folder in storage folder with subfolders `public/storage/newdirectory`. when i try to change it to `../public/storage` then i get error message `"Path is outside of the defined root"`. Any idea how can i change it?

From internet found somethin like this: `public_path("/storage/newdirectory");`
and it doesn't helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

```
File::makeDirectory(public_path('storage/newdirectory'));
```

Comment: `Class 'App\Features\Api\File' not found `

Comment: Use full path `\File::` or add use clause at the top of the class as with any other facade.

Answer (score 0):

By default laravel takes `storage` directory as root directory.

Change the root directoy info in `filesystems.php`

```
'local' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => '/path/to/your/directory',
],
```